# Linux Server - Paths

Tags: javascript, php, linux, dom

On a Linux server, I am trying to access files in a separate folder on the same server, but can't quite seem to reach them. The PHP script is located in a subdomain folder:

```
/home/sofia/public_html/mail.domain1.com/index.php
```

and I am trying to load an image resource from a different folder, with absolute paths like these *(JavaScript DOM)*:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('/home/sofia/public_html/common-res/bgImage.jpg')";
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('/home/sofia/common-res/bgImage.jpg')";
```

or even with relative paths:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../common-res/bgImage.jpg')";
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../common-res/bgImage.jpg')";
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax, or are such references simply not allowed?

Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: use relative path - like `http://www.example.com/....` for url attribute

Comment: Hi Prava, and thank you; that works. Is there any reason why we can't use relative paths like *../../common-res/bgImage.jpg*?

Comment: for url image, absolute path never works :). It must be a virtual path. In other words, relative to the application web
directory.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, Prava. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local paths such as `/home/sofia/common-res/bgImage.jpg` will not work. You must either use full or relative URLs:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../common-res/bgImage.jpg')";
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://example.com/common-res/bgImage.jpg')";
```

Both are acceptable, just make sure they resolve to a directory that is properly being served.

Comment: Referencing the actual URL, *h.t.t.p:/./example.com/...* works, but not the relative path. Thank you. You said, *"make sure they resolve to a directory that is properly being served."* Could that be the reason the relative paths are not working?

Comment: @iSofia yes. Make sure the absolute path you are pointing to works properly.

Comment: Yes; apparently that was the problem all along. Thank you Yuval.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for the benefit of others. Support from my hosting company has informed me that for such servers where multiple domains reside on a single account, each domain or sub-domain in the *public_html* folder is treated as a separate domain, and thus cannot breach the cross-domain protocol.

However, since they are on the same server, a simple solution would be to create symlinks within each domain or sub-domain, to enable them to access local resources beyond their scope.

In any case, the solution offered by Yuval Adam and Prava works just as well. Thank you both.

It should also be noted, that depending on the host server configuration, referencing a *http* path would incur connection overheads, while relative references do not.